# How do I prove that this specific claim is onto?

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation, alternative-proof

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function and define a new function $h: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ via $h(x) = 2f(x) + 3$. If $f$ is onto, the $h$ is also onto.

Comment: You will have to use the fact that $f$ is onto.

Comment: Yes, I am now realizing that I did not phrase my question very well. I edited it to be more direct.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ than we want to find $y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $2f(y)+3=x$. We know that there exists $z \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(z) =\frac{x-3}{2}$. Define $y=z$ and its easy to see that the indeed $2f(z)+3=x$.

Comment: This question goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.